# Why are my two charts repeating the same label?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have to two bar charts Which are generated using ChartJS.
The top and bottom graphs are sharing the same label for some reason?

```
  var data = {
      labels: [],
      datasets: [
          {
              fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
              strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.8)",
              highlightFill: "rgba(151,187,205,0.75)",
              highlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)"
          }
      ]
  };
  var options = {
      animation: true,
      responsive: true
  };


  var ctx1 = document.getElementById("february-chart").getContext("2d");
  februaryChart = new Chart(ctx1).Bar(data, options);

  var ctx2 = document.getElementById("march-chart").getContext("2d");
  marchChart = new Chart(ctx2).Bar(data, options);


  februaryChart.addData([2], 'aaaa');
  marchChart.addData([5], 'bbbb');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4tg2uvc6/

Comment: I think the `addData` method is updating the variable you pass in as data. As its used in both charts they both get updated. this is just speculation but this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4tg2uvc6/1/) seems to confirm it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because they are sharing a reference to the same data object. When you invoke the addData method, they are both changing the same object. Provide different data objects to each instance, you can still share the options, assuming you want them to be the same.

https://jsfiddle.net/onug1tdy/

```
var marchData = {
    labels: [],
    datasets: [
        {
            fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.8)",
            highlightFill: "rgba(151,187,205,0.75)",
            highlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)"
        }
    ]
};
var febData = {
    labels: [],
    datasets: [
        {
            fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.8)",
            highlightFill: "rgba(151,187,205,0.75)",
            highlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)"
        }
    ]
};
var options = {
    animation: true,
    responsive: true
};



var ctx1 = document.getElementById("february-chart").getContext("2d");
februaryChart = new Chart(ctx1).Bar(febData, options);

var ctx2 = document.getElementById("march-chart").getContext("2d");
marchChart = new Chart(ctx2).Bar(marchData, options);


februaryChart.addData([2], 'aaaa');
marchChart.addData([5], 'bbbb');
```